# KEEPA API Experience

Tags: api, json, python

I'm trying to pull historical prices and BSR from about 3,000 ASINs on Amazon, but need something built to interface with Keepa's API.  Does anyone have any experience with this?  If so, is there a software program that can be licensed? Or does it have to be customized third-party software?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking how to use the KEEPA API or something more complicated?

Comment: How would I go about pulling one price per day (that day’s earliest listed price) per asin going back 180 days using Python module KeepaAPI? I assume the LISTPRICE key is correct to use but having trouble pulling only one price per day for most recent 189 days. [Relevant section Keepa Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G68Qh.png)

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming you’re looking for something to make this api work easier, rather than resorting to hand coding. I would suggest Talend’s [Data Services Platform](https://www.talend.com/products/application-integration/data-services-platform/).

I think Talend is the best tool around; but of course that’s why I work for a Talend...

For an unbiased viewpoint, Forrester gives Talend the highest score among all data fabrics. =)